# Adding colours from .style file to multiple shapefiles via script?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, style, color

I have added 70 fill colours in a .style file. For adding these colours to my shapefile i would have to manually go to properties/symbology/match to symbols in a style/ then browse to the location where my style file is saved, add it, click on Apply for the colours to change. I do not want to do this for each shapefile.

Is there a script which when run would call this .style file and add its colours to the shapefiles in my workspace?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include details like your ArcGIS for Desktop version, and whether you are seeking to apply all 70 fill colours each time you add a layer from a shapefile, please?  If it is the latter than perhaps making a single layer file that you "clone" and change the source of will work.

Comment: Have you looked into adding color maps: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000009w000000